# How can I google search for a phrase with one word optional?

Tags: google-search

I want to search for all phrases "the [something] effect", with any word substituting for [something].

Thus "The Rosie Effect", the "The butterfly effect", etc, should all be included.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use a [wildcard `*`](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/2466433).

Example:

> ["The * effect"](https://www.google.com/#q=The+*+effect)